# Google Apps Script and curl

Tags: curl, google-apps-script, access-token

This is probably a very simple problem, but I am pretty new to `curl` and have never had it properly explained. This is the first time I have had to get an access token via `curl` and I have never seen an example. My google searches have not been helpful.

I know how to make the transaction requests once I have the access token, but can't get the token to move on to that step.

Below is the api documentation example of how to get the token:

```
curl -X POST -u <API USERNAME>:<API SECRET KEY> https://api.neverbounce.com/v3/access_token\
-d grant_type=client_credentials\
-d scope=basic+user
```

How am I supposed to make this call in `Google Apps Script` since `UrlFetchApp` requires a url, but the url in this example is part of the request?

**UPDATE**

This is a sample of my code:

```
function NBpost() {
  var dataString = 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=basic+user';
  var url = "https://api.neverbounce.com/v3/access_token";
  var options =
    {
      "method" : "post",
      "auth": {
        'user': <USERNAME>,
        'pass': <SECRET KEY>,
      },
      body : dataString,
      "muteHttpExceptions" : true
    };
  var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText());
}
```

The response is always the same:

```
error:"invalid_request", 
error_description:"The grant type was not specified in the request"
```

I have also tried:

```
var dataString = {
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "scope" : "basic user"
};
```

But the response does not change. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2**

I made the following changes:

```
function myFunction(){
    var url ='https://api.neverbounce.com/v3/access_token';
    var options = {
      method: "post",
      u: {
        <USERNAME> : <SECRET KEY>
      },
      payload: {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "scope": "basic user"
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };
    var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText());
}
```

Now, I get this error:

```
error:"invalid_client"
error_description:"Client credentials were not found in the headers or body"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about following sample script? I don't know whether this works fine, because I don't have `<API USERNAME>` and `<API SECRET KEY>`.

**Sample script :**

```
var apiusername = <API USERNAME>
var apisecretkey = <API SECRET KEY>
var url ='https://api.neverbounce.com/v3/access_token';
var options = {
  method: 'post',
  headers : {"Authorization" : " Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(apiusername + ":" + apisecretkey)},
  payload: {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "scope": "basic+user"
  },
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};
var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText());
```

If this doesn't work or if I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but I get this error: `Exception: Login information disallowed`

Comment: I'm sorry. I updated it just now.  It included the basic authentication to header. Please try it.